# Moving error bars in a line graph with three factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph, errorbar

I am trying to make the error bars black in a line graph that has three factors....

```r
structure(list(pot = c(41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 101L, 102L, 
103L, 104L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 89L, 
90L, 91L, 92L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 113L, 
114L, 115L, 116L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L
), rep = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), cultivar = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Dinninup", "Riverina", 
"Seaton Park", "Yarloop"), class = "factor"), Waterlogging = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Non-waterlogged", 
"Waterlogged"), class = "factor"), P = c(12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 
24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35), form = c(2.81, 2.64, 2.59, 3.28, 3.18, 2.57, 2.9, 
3, 2.38, 2.72, 2.58, 2.73, 3.06, 3.01, 3.01, 2.77, 2.95, 2.36, 
2.91, 2.38, 3.33, 3.19, 3.17, 3.16, 3.16, 3.2, 2.58, 3.71, 3.11, 
2.7, 2.92, 1.93, 2.95, 2.57, 2.68, 2.48, 3.34, 2.75, 2.52, 1.88, 
1.19, 0.57, 0.64, 0.66, 1.13, 1.28, 0.85, 0.96, 1.34, 2.14, 0.63, 
1.27, 1.13, 0.64, 1.21, 1.95, 1.11, 0.91, 0.75, 0.63, 1.06, 1.07, 
1.05, 0.8, 1.41, 1.13, 0.75, 0.89, 1.98, 1.27, 1.01, 1, 1.16, 
0.64, 0.64, 1.02, 1.03, 1.13, 0.79, 0.6)), row.names = 41:120, class = "data.frame")
```

```r
library(Rmisc)
library(ggplot2)

tglf3 <- summarySE(yar, measurevar="form", 
groupvars=c("P","cultivar","Waterlogging"),na.rm=TRUE)
pd <- position_dodge(0.5)

ggplot(tglf3,aes(x=P, y=form, colour=Waterlogging, shape=cultivar))+ 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se), width=.6,position=pd) +
  geom_point(size=3.5,position=pd) +
  geom_line(position=pd) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.direction="vertical")
```

[image: Coloured error bars]

When I try to change the colour, this happens...

```r
ggplot(tglf3,aes(x=P, y=form, colour=Waterlogging, shape=cultivar)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se), colour="black", width=.6,position=pd) +
  geom_point(size=3.5,position=pd) +
  geom_line(position=pd) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.direction="vertical")
```

[image: The issue]

The three factors are water-logging, cultivar and phosphorus. I have tried adding 'group=cultivar' which usually works when there are only two factors.

```r
ggplot(tglf3,aes(x=P, y=form, colour=Waterlogging, shape=cultivar,group=cultivar)) + ...
```

[image: Example legend]

Comment: In your example, what is `position = pd` ? Also, what is `se` ? Both are not defined in your code.

Comment: Do you want with different color ? On two columns ?

Comment: In the legend shown in the black and white example, we can see that the Riverina label has two symbols next to it, the two which are actually plotted in the graph.  The symbols are aligned in rows and are labelled at the start of the row with the name of the factor level. It is not the clearest display, however, it is better than what ggplot produces. It is better than ggplot's legend because the symbols are identical to those plotted.

Comment: I edited my answer, does it look what you are expecting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code, you can have `color` and `shape` grouped in legend and have a unique legend shape for each category as in your example.

To have your legend in two columns, you can use `guides`.

```r
ggplot(DF2, aes(x = P, y = form, 
                 shape = interaction(cultivar, Waterlogging), 
                 color = interaction(cultivar, Waterlogging),
                 group = interaction(cultivar, Waterlogging)))+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se),color = "black", width=.6, 
                  position = pd)+
    geom_point(size = 3.5)+
    geom_line()+
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = 'top', 
          legend.direction="vertical")+
    guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2, title = "Legend"), 
           shape = guide_legend(ncol =2, title = "Legend"))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: position = pd is there because I want the error bars "dodged" so they don't overlap. So I am trying to achieve the first plot on top but the error bars should be black

Comment: I need the symbols in the legend to be identical to those shown in the plot.

Comment: Are you looking for having `cultivar` and `waterlogging` into the same legend ? with 4 labels ?

Comment: I have added an example legend to the post. I need the legend icons to be identical to those shown in the plot. This is the usual standard but ggplot does not produce it with the above graph

Comment: Do not add it to my answer but rather edit your question.

Comment: That's pretty good! You can get the error bars in a better position by adding  "position = pd" into:   geom_point(size = 3.5,position = pd)+
    geom_line(position = pd)+