# Changing the style of symbols in the legend so they are identical to those shown on the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying change the legend so it is more representative of what is shown on the plot and is up to a publishing standard.

Here is an example I am trying to follow....

[image: desired result]

As you can see, the symbols in the legend are identical to those shown in the plot.

Here is my graph....

[image: My graph]

I am not happy with the legend that ggplot produces and I cant find a way to alter it so it matches the published example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could just modify the the answer to your previous question by @dc37 [Moving error bars in a line graph with three factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906833/moving-error-bars-in-a-line-graph-with-three-factors). I only added two lines for `linetype`.

```
library(Rmisc)
library(ggplot2)
tglf3 <- summarySE(df, measurevar="form", 
                 groupvars=c("P","cultivar","Waterlogging"),na.rm=TRUE)
pd <- position_dodge(0.5)
ggplot(tglf3,aes(x=P, y=form, 
                 shape = interaction(cultivar, Waterlogging), 
                 color = interaction(cultivar, Waterlogging),
                 linetype = interaction(cultivar, Waterlogging)))+ 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se), width=.6,position=pd) +
  geom_point(size=3.5,position=pd) +
  geom_line(position=pd) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'top') +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2, title = "Legend"), 
         shape = guide_legend(ncol =2, title = "Legend"), 
         linetype = guide_legend(ncol =2, title = "Legend"))
```

[image]

#### Edit

Initially, I thought it cannot be done in `ggplot2`, but I have managed to trick `ggplot2` to get what you want(?). I have learned some new tricks through this.

```
p <-ggplot(tglf3, aes(x=P, y=form, 
                 color = interaction(cultivar, Waterlogging),     
                 shape = interaction(cultivar, Waterlogging), 
                 linetype = interaction(cultivar, Waterlogging)))+ 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se), width=.6,position=pd) +
  geom_point(size=3.5,position=pd) +
  geom_line(position=pd) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'top') +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(ncol=2, title = "Riverina \nYarloop"), 
         shape = guide_legend(ncol =2, title = "Riverina \nYarloop"), 
         color =  guide_legend(ncol =2, title = "Riverina \nYarloop"))
df <- droplevels(df)
brks <- levels(interaction(df$cultivar, df$Waterlogging))
lbs <- c("Non-waterlogged",  "Non-waterlogged", "Waterlogged", "Waterlogged")
p + scale_shape_discrete(breaks=brks, labels=lbs) +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks=brks, labels=lbs) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(breaks=brks, labels=lbs)
```

[image]

#### Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(pot = c(41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 101L, 102L, 
103L, 104L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 89L, 
90L, 91L, 92L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 113L, 
114L, 115L, 116L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L
), rep = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), cultivar = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Dinninup", "Riverina", 
"Seaton Park", "Yarloop"), class = "factor"), Waterlogging = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Non-waterlogged", 
"Waterlogged"), class = "factor"), P = c(12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 
24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35), form = c(2.81, 2.64, 2.59, 3.28, 3.18, 2.57, 2.9, 
3, 2.38, 2.72, 2.58, 2.73, 3.06, 3.01, 3.01, 2.77, 2.95, 2.36, 
2.91, 2.38, 3.33, 3.19, 3.17, 3.16, 3.16, 3.2, 2.58, 3.71, 3.11, 
2.7, 2.92, 1.93, 2.95, 2.57, 2.68, 2.48, 3.34, 2.75, 2.52, 1.88, 
1.19, 0.57, 0.64, 0.66, 1.13, 1.28, 0.85, 0.96, 1.34, 2.14, 0.63, 
1.27, 1.13, 0.64, 1.21, 1.95, 1.11, 0.91, 0.75, 0.63, 1.06, 1.07, 
1.05, 0.8, 1.41, 1.13, 0.75, 0.89, 1.98, 1.27, 1.01, 1, 1.16, 
0.64, 0.64, 1.02, 1.03, 1.13, 0.79, 0.6)), row.names = 41:120, class = "data.frame")
```